# Would like to clean up my VM situation

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant, virtualbox, puppet

Almost a year ago, with significant help from others, I set up my first ever VM - on Windows 7, created with PuPHPet/Puppet, run by Vagrant, and normally powered up from inside PHPStorm 7.1. At first, in the process of figuring out the best way to do things, I ended up with two vagrant directories and three server boxes (in fact, PHPStorm thinks there are 4!), but as far as I know, I only use one. I didn't really worry about that at the time, but now I want to clean things up.

The file structure where the boxes are looks like this:

```
+---aD9J5x_default_1392259764499_9862
|   |   aD9J5x_default_1392259764499_9862.vbox
|   |   aD9J5x_default_1392259764499_9862.vbox-prev
|   |   
|   +---Logs
|   |       VBox.log
|   |       VBox.log.1
|   |       VBox.log.2
|   |       VBox.log.3
|   |       
|   \---Snapshots
+---CentOS-6.4-x86_64
|       box-disk1.vmdk
|       
+---CentOS6-64
|   |   CentOS6-64.vbox
|   |   CentOS6-64.vbox-prev
|   |   CentOS6-64.vhd
|   |   
|   \---Logs
|           VBox.log
|           VBox.log.1
|           VBox.log.2
|           
+---vagrant-phalcon_default_1392529509013_7326
|   |   vagrant-phalcon_default_1392529509013_7326.vbox
|   |   vagrant-phalcon_default_1392529509013_7326.vbox-prev
|   |   
|   \---Logs
|           VBox.log
|           
\---z8lEcJ_default_1383507440
        box-disk1.vmdk
```

The aD9J5x... folder has the logs that are recent, and "aD9J5x" is also the name of the folder with the vagrant/puppet files (PuPHPet named it, not me - I would have never made it that cryptic!), so that is clearly part of the picture. But there is no actual server file (big file ending in .vhd or .vmdk) there. Sleuthing in Oracle VM, it says that the "hard drive" attached to aD9J5x_default... is the one in the x81EcJ_default... folder - go figure.

[image: Oracle screenshot "Oracle screenshot"]

(I don't know why the virtual sizes and actual sizes of the three are inversely related, but that's beside the point.)

However, looking at the vagrant/puppet stuff, the picture is different. In my "dev" folder that I set up for this stuff, there are two folders that have the basic vagrant-like structure, with a Vagrantfile at the top and some stuff underneath: `C:\dev\puphpet\aD9J5x` and `C:\dev\vagrant-phalcon`. I can run vagrant from either place, but only aD9J5x sets up a shared folder for /var/www so that I can do development. But what's curious is that vagrant-phalcon's contents were created four days after aD9J5x and its parent, and it has far more stuff (396 files in 93 folders vs. only 21 files/11 folders in aD9J5x), including the installation of Phalcon and its devtools, which are critical to my situation. So I can't help but wonder if the vagrant-phalcon folder is needed somehow, even though I never start vagrant from there.

I know that `C:\dev\puphpet` was created from a zip file downloaded from the online PuPHPet utility. I don't have any memory of where `C:\dev\vagrant-phalcon` came from. And I am a green newbie at all this - I only know two vagrant commands (up and halt), and have almost no clue how to find my way around a puppet configuration or how to use the Oracle VM software to do anything useful.

My questions:

1. How can I tell whether I need the C:\vagrant-phalcon files for anything? I would hope that I can repeat the process of creating this server (the whole point of puppet), but at the moment it looks like neither of those two folders has everything needed to configure a server with both Phalcon and my shared folder.
2. Is is safe to remove the machine that doesn't seem to be called anywhere (the one that uses a .vhd file)? I assume the cleanest way to do that is inside the Oracle software rather than just nuking the folder...
3. Can I safely rename "aD9J5x" to something more intelligible as long as I do it for both the folder in the above tree and the PuPHPet folder, or is there someplace else that needs to change?
4. Is there a way to consolidate the folder with the logs and the folder with the box-disk? The other two boxes are neatly consolidated in a single folder, but that one, which is probably the only one I need to keep long-term, is broken into two, and I don't know why. Since this was created with Puppet, I guess I would need to make a change somewhere in the Puppet manifest also...

Thanks in advance for thoughts on any of these. I will happily provide additional info on request.

Comment: manage with Vagrant, you needn't take care the display in Virtualbox. The way you are working on is in wrong direction.

Comment: @BMW: Once I know what I should do, I'm happy to do it using Vagrant - I don't normally run the Oracle software anyway. `vagrant box list` says I have 4 boxes: 'CentOS 6.5 x86_64', 'CentOS 6.5 x86_64 Puppet', 'centos-64-x64', and 'centos64-x64-vbox43-1383512148'. Apparently one of those four doesn't actually have a "hard disk" file.

Comment: Then just delete them with `vagrant box remove`. With `Vagrantfile` on your hand, you can start your environment easily.

Comment: I know that's the theory, but for me it's not that simple. I have made changes to my box (mostly the nginx config) that are not reflected in my Vagrant/Puppet files (because I know a bit about how to configure a server but almost nothing about how to put those configurations in the complex Puppet files that PuPHPet built for me). And as I said, it looks like two of my Vagrant folders contain parts of what's needed - one is where I boot from, and the other contains lots of files that look necessary. I also can't correlate the 4 box names with my different folders, to know which is which.

Comment: ic, you need source control the puppet codes, and change and update only from puppet, then `vagrant provision`. But if you need keep the old one and want to do a clean, try this command: `vagrant global-status --prune`

Comment: I hear you - I'll try to get the ear of the PuPHPet guy in Dallas to help me understand the labyrinth of the code his tool produces, so I can start using the right workflow that you described. Meanwhile, I tried your command suggestion, but my vagrant doesn't seem to know "global-status" as a command. Different version? (I have 1.4.3)

Comment: yes, different version `Installed Version: 1.7.0`

Comment: I think I just hung myself. I upgraded vangrant, but now when I run `vagrant -global-status` it says: "There are no active Vagrant environments on this computer! Or, you haven't destroyed and recreated Vagrant environments that were started with an older version of Vagrant." Yeah, they were started with an older version, but the one I actually use (whichever one that is) contains changes (especially to nginx config) that are not reflected in Puppet, so I'm not ready to destroy it. Suggestions for my next step?